# Trying to print out the return of a getchar() != EOF of all inputted chars

Tags: c, eof

Bit confused with the current code.
Studying at Uni and currently going through **The C Programming Language (2nd Edition) by Brian W. Kernighan**

Now I've been programming for a good few years mainly in C++ and a bit of java, however not really played with C that much and something is really bugging me.

So exercise 1-6 in the book wants you to prove that the char read by `getchar()` would be either `1` or `0`

Now I fully understand that it reads the char in the buffer and checks to see if it's not `EOF`, if so it returns `1` else `0`

This means that if I type `a` and press enter it reads the `a` and the enter and returns `1,1`
Also if I use `CTRL+D` it returns `0` because it causes a `EOF`. The issue I have and where i fail to understand the logic is: when i type `aa Ctrl+D`,
the way I read it it should print `1,1,0` as it reads the `a,a` then `EOF`, however it seems to print `1,1` then wait for the next input.

Why is this?

Here is the code I have written so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;

    while(c = (getchar() != EOF)) // Read char in buffer and check to see if it's EOF or not, then assign a 1 or 0 to c
    {
        printf("1 Not End Of File\n");  
    }
    printf("0 End Of File\n");  
}
```

Obviously I could use `printf("%d",c);` to show if its a `1` or `0`, but the issue still stands..

Why when I do `aa ctrl+D` does it not print

```
1 Not End Of File
1 Not End Of File
0 End Of File?
```

Also I'm fully aware this same question has been answered on the site before however it seems no one has answered this specific issue in detail, they instead seem to say how `getchar()` gets one char and reads it and how the while exits when its a `EOF`, but not why the next line isn't ran if a `EOF` is added to a few chars.

It seems to read the two `a`'s and then rather than set `c` to `0` when it should reach the `CTRL+D` and then exit the while, it seems to sit and wait for more input?

Comment: You might be seeing some issues concerning terminal input, nothing to do with your C code at all.  Try comparing these three experiments: (1) "a a RETURN CTRL+D", (2) "a a CTRL+D", (3) "a a CTRL+D CTRL+D".

Comment: You see that's what I thought. I had tested all three experiments, 1) returns 1,1,1 then waits for input and ctrl+d then outputs 0... 2) returns 1,1 then waits for input..  3) returns 1,1 waits for input then 0

Comment: That's the expected result, and it's consistent with Shiping's answer.  The Unix/Linux terminal driver accumulates characters and does not deliver them to your program until (a) you hit Return or (b) you hit Control-D.  Also, if it's at the beginning of a line (that is, if it's preceded by a newline), control-D generates EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Ctl-D is just to trigger the program to read the input.  Because you have typed some characters, the program have something to read and doesn't see the end of the input. Type Ctl-D alone, the program tries to read input but sees nothing there and takes it as having reached to the end of the input. Like to add that Ctl-D itself is not passed to getchar() to be read as input.